# lucene.net phonetic filter

Tags: c#, lucene.net, phonetics

I am trying to store text data to lucene.

The search should be with phonetic!

Where should I add a phonetic filter?

```
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir =
FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\Index"));

IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(dir, true);
Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
//IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(dir, true);
//Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
Analyzer analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.De.GermanAnalyzer();

//Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29,"content", analyzer);
var query = queryParser.Parse(textBox1.Text+"~0.8");

Console.WriteLine("Searching for: " + query.ToString());
TopDocs resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(query, indexReader.MaxDoc());

Console.WriteLine("Results Found: " + resultDocs.TotalHits)
```

Regards, Ingo

Comment: Do you have a phonetic tokenizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to implement an `Analyzer` that adds it to the `TokenStream` chain, or use a TokenStream directly.

ie:

```
System.IO.TextReader someText = ....;
TokenStream phonetics = new PhoneticFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(new WhitespaceTokenizer(someText )));
```

Replace `PhoneticFilter` with the `TokenFilter` you implemented, and use this both at search and index time.