# Implement smart search / Fuzzy string comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, soundex

I have a web page on an ASP.NET MVC application where customers search for suppliers. The suppliers capture their own details on the website. The client wants a "smart search" feature, where they could search for suppliers and find them even if the supplier spelling is "slightly different" to what is typed in the search box.

I have no idea what the client's notion of "slightly different" is. I've been looking into implementing a custom soundex algorithm. This converts a word into a number based on how it sounds. That number is then used for comparison.

For example:

> Zach
>
> Zack

will encode to the same value. Are there any other options I could possible look into?

Comment: this link may help you -a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933464/how-to-build-a-search-engine-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) combined with a 'tags' field on Suppliers in your database for 'smart search' style functionality.

It's pretty basic but works for well for cases such as 'Zack/Zach'.

Adding tags in your database allows you to handle situations where people may search for a supplier by their acronym or other colloquial name.

See [How to calculate distance similarity measure of given 2 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9453731/242) and http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein for implementation details.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me find this [library](https://fuzzystring.codeplex.com/) on codeplex that implements Levenshtein distance (and many other algorithms) and seems really easy to use. I'm going to give it a try :)

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction. Nice find on the FuzzyString library.

Answer (score 8):

What you need is an indexed search with a phonetic analysis filter.

Lucene.NET offers just that.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-phonetic/org/apache/lucene/analysis/phonetic/PhoneticFilterFactory.html

[How to perform Phonetic and Aproximative search in Lucene.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223637/how-to-perform-phonetic-and-aproximative-search-in-lucene-net)

See here for the .NET version of Phonetix:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phonetixnet/

Here some more info on how to implement it in C#:
[lucene.net phonetic filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529126/lucene-net-phonetic-filter)

You can also use a [BeiderMorseEncoder](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/analyzers-phonetic/org/apache/lucene/analysis/phonetic/BeiderMorseFilter.html), which is designed to handle [many languages](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/BeiderMorseEncoder.html).

On the subject of finding similarly spelled words, why not using a fuzzy search instead ? 
[how to do fuzzy search in Lucene.net in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851208/how-to-do-fuzzy-search-in-lucene-net-in-asp-net)
[Lucene.net Fuzzy Phrase Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053716/lucene-net-fuzzy-phrase-search)

There are also a whole lot of string metrics functions that you could use via CLR-Stored-Procedure:
http://anastasiosyal.com/post/2009/01/11/Beyond-SoundEx-Functions-for-Fuzzy-Searching-in-MS-SQL-Server